# Unable to instantiate nested exception class due to constructor not found

Tags: groovy

I want to define a `BarException` inside of class `Foo` for namespacing reason. This is what my `Foo` class looks like:

```
package org.company.utils

class Foo {                                                                                                                               
    class BarException extends RuntimeException { }

    def raise() {                                                                                                                             
        def r = new RuntimeException("BOOM")                                                                                                    
        throw new BarException(r)
    }
}
```

This is how I would have liked it to work:

```
  void testFoo() {
    shouldFail(Foo.BarException) {
      def foo = new Foo()
      foo.raise()
    }
  }
```

But the test failed with:

> 1) testFoo(test.FooTestCase)java.lang.AssertionError: Closure
>   test.FooTestCase$_testFoo_closure1@3eb25e1a should have failed with an
>   exception of type org.company.utils.Foo$BarException, instead got
>   Exception groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching
>   constructor for:
>   org.company.utils.Foo$BarException(org.company.utils.Foo,
>   java.lang.RuntimeException)

I have tried instantiating BarException using `new BarException(this, r)`, and putting `groovy.transform.InheritConstructors` around `BarException`, but nothing works for the compiler.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making BarException static and add `@InheritConstructors`.

```
import groovy.transform.InheritConstructors

class Foo {
    @InheritConstructors
    static class BarException extends Exception { }

    def raise() {
        Throwable r = new RuntimeException("BOOM")
        throw new BarException(r)
    }
}
```

From the [groovy docs](http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_static_inner_classes):

> The usage of static inner classes is the best supported one. If you
>   absolutely need an inner class, you should make it a static one.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer addressed my problem, but if possible I would also like to have an explanation of why without `static` my thinking doesn't work.

Comment: What version of groovy are you using?

Comment: `Groovy Version: 2.4.11 JVM: 1.8.0_144 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X`